# Python 3.6 on linux: Problem with flushing what i want to write to the stdout

Tags: python, linux, stdout, flush, sys

I'm pretty new to python and linux and I'm running into a problem...

So I'm trying to run the following code 
*(It is supposed to inform the person in front of the terminal, that the program is still running and then delete that line after 1 second)*:

```
import sys

while True:
   # do something

   sys.stdout.write("Still going...")
   time.sleep(1)
   sys.stdout.write("\r")
   sys.stdout.flush()
```

This works perfectly fine on windows on python 3.8, but when i run it on my linux vps with python 3.6.9 via the "python3" command it doesn't flush the "\r", so the "Still going..." line only gets deleted and immediately reprinted the next time it reaches sys.stdout.write("Still going...").

If anyone has an idea what's going on here - please tell me
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is there a reason you do not want to use `print` (which has an optional argument `flush`)?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know how to delete something I wrote with "print" after a specific time.
I know you can do: >>> print("some text", end="\r"), but this just deletes it instantly and I don't see how that could ever be of use for anyone.

Is there a way to do it with print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows, Mac OS and UNIXes code new lines with differents chars.

- Windows uses `\r\n`
- Mac OS uses `\r`
- UNIXes use `\n`

if you want your program to be cross-platform, you should use [`os.linesep`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html?highlight=linesep#os.linesep) instead of an OS-specific linebreak

---

answering the comment:

Indeed on Windows, `\r` just return at the start of the line while `\n` actually starts a new line (see [this StackExchange anwser](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29075/difference-between-n-and-r-n) for a nice explanation).

I assume that, on windows, it allows you to simply write on the same line until the program exits.

Sadly it could work at least with some terminals on UNIXes but not necessarily on every terminals...

As a work around, you could probably use the `\b` character which deletes the last caracter of the line, like the `[backspace]` key.

Comment: oh hm... this confuses me a bit... "\r" deletes the current line and "\n" starts a new one...
Also it's not, that "\r" itself is not working, it just isn't printed to the screen when it's called, but rather the next time something else gets printed

Comment: Edit: I just figured something out: I was under a misapprehension on where the error lies buried.... "\r" apparently only placed the cursor at the beginning of the line on UNIXes(?)... any idea what actually deletes the line, like "\r" does on Windows?

Comment: Edit 2: idk how to edit a comment, so I just have to do this over and over again...
For the time being i decided to just do:
>>> sys.stdout.write("\r")
>>> sys.stdout.write("                                                    ")  # a lot of empty spaces here, which the website wont let me show
>>> sys.stdout.write("\r")
... to basically place the cursor at the beginning of the line, print a lot of empty spaces and then set it back to the beginning again.

Comment: @Jurb it is a valid workaround. By searching a little, you could find packages which handle this for you. Or you could use `\b` char as an other workaround.